# Docker: copy file and directory with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created one Docker Image for a custom application which needs some license files (some files and one directory) to run, so I'm using the COPY command in the `Dockerfile` to copy license file to the image:

```
# Base image: Application installed on Debian 10 but unlicensed
FROM me/application-unlicensed

# Copy license files
COPY *.license /opt/application/
COPY application-license-dir /var/lib/application-license-dir
```

I use this `Dockerfile` to build a new image with the license for a single container. As I have 5 different licenses I created 5 different images each with one specific license file and directory.

The licenses are also fixed to a **MAC Address**, so when I run one of the five container I specify its own MAC Address with the `--mac-address` parameter:

```
docker run --rm --mac-address AB:CD:EF:12:34:56 me/application-license1
```

This work, but I wish to have a better and smarter way to manage this:

As with `docker-compose` is it possible to specify the container MAC Address, could I just use the unlicensed base image and copy license files and the license directory when I build the 5 containers with `docker-compose`?

---

**Edit: let me better explain the structure of license files**

The application is deployed into `/opt/application` directory into the Docker image.

License files (`*.license`) are into the `/opt/application` at the same level of the application itself, to they cannot be saved into a Docker volume unless I create some symlinks (but I have to check if the application will work this way).

The directory application-license-dir needs to be at `/var/lib/application-license-dir`, so it can be mounted into a Docker volume (I have to check if the application will work but I think so).

Both `*.license` files and the files into the `application-license-dir` are binary, so I cannot script or create them at runtime.

So:

1. can `docker-compose` create a local directory on the Docker host
   server before binding and mounting it to a Docker volume?
2. can `docker-compose` copy my licenses file and my license directory from
   the GIT repository (locally cloned) to the local directory created
   during the step 1?
3. can `docker-compose` create some symlinks into the
   container's `/opt/application` directory for the `*.license` files
   stored into the volume?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For things that are different every time you run a container or when you run a container on a different system, you generally don't want to specify these in a Dockerfile.  This includes the license files you show above; things like user IDs also match this pattern; depending on how fixed your configuration files are they can also count.  (For things that are *the same* every time you run the container, you do want these in your image; especially this is the application source code.)

You can use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to inject files into a container at run time.  There is Compose syntax for bind mounts using the [`volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) directive.

This would give you a Compose file roughly like:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: me/application-unlicensed
    volumes:
      - './app1.license:/opt/application/app.license'
      - './application-license-dir:/var/lib/application-license-dir'
    mac_address: 'AB:CD:EF:12:34:56'
```

Bind mounts like this are a good match for pushing configuration files into containers.  They can provide an empty host directory into which log files can be written, but aren't otherwise a mechanism for copying data out of an image.  They're also useful as a place to store data that needs to outlive a container, if your application can't store all of its state in an external database.

Comment: Thanks! Can the `app1.license` volume be a file? So what I'm understanding is that Docker Compose cannot dynamically deploy the container, so I should create some script (Fabric, for example) to copy the license files into the volume directory and create the Docker Compose file based on the license I'm deploying (I have 5 licenses and every license has different files/directory and one license can have a different number of `.license` files to copy on the volume attached to the container.

Comment: Yes, it can.  If you look at that line carefully, I'm intending a container-specific `app1.license` file to be mounted into the fixed `/opt/application` directory in the container, so you can repeat this (with different files) for each container.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this commit](https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/b76ac6e6) docker-compose has `mac_address` support.
Mounting license files with `-v` could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can set mac_address for the different containers as
`mac_address: AB:CD:EF:12:34:12`. For documentation reference [see this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)

For creating multiple instances from the same image, you will have to copy paste each app block 5 times in your docker-compose file and in each you can set a different mac_adddress

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that license files and directory files are binary so I cannot script them, I need to copy them into the container.

Comment: you can attach them in the container using volumes. This can be done from the docker-compose file. If you want to know more about that, see this,  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes , try a few options, it should work. if it doesnt work, do create another question as its a different topic, i'll check it :)

Comment: I edited the question adding more information about the license file and directory, to understand if docker-compose can manage the entire deploy process, or I need some external scripts like Fabric script or something like it.